# Restrict the use of underscore('_') in input textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, html

regex which allows utf-8 characters but restricts underscore abd specials chracters (except this one -).
it is allowing underscore.I want to restrict it.
This my demo code :
https://plnkr.co/edit/Solap6eBGssvn7wVjkFn?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function demoMatchClick() {
      var re = new RegExp(document.demoMatch.regex.value);
      if (document.demoMatch.subject.value.match(re)) {
        alert("Successful match");
      } else {
        alert("No match");
      }
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  <P>regEx for unicode characters :</P>
  <FORM ID="demoMatch" NAME="demoMatch" METHOD=POST ACTION="javascript:void(0)">
    <P>Regexp:
      <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="regex" VALUE="^([^\x00-\x7F]|[\w_\ \-])+$" SIZE=50>
    </P>
    <P>Subject string:
      <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="subject" VALUE="This is a test of the JavaScript RegExp object" SIZE=50>
    </P>
    <P>
      <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Test Match" ONCLICK="demoMatchClick()">
    </P>
  </FORM>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then just change `[\w_\ \-]` to `[\w\ \-]`? That removes `_` for the character set in your regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use some jQuery. Check wich key is down on input, and if it's the minus AND shift, prevent it.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="js-input">
```

JS

```
// get field
var field = document.querySelector('.js-input');

// add keydown listener
field.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // 189 === minus 
  // with shift === _
    if (e.which === 189 && e.shiftKey === true) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jrck9m2r/1/

Edit:
The answer of @Gaurav doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/Ley8mc19/2/

Comment: your solution is working at my side. How can we integrate it with my existing code. https://plnkr.co/edit/Solap6eBGssvn7wVjkFn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use some jquery

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function(event){
  if(event.which==95){
    return false;
  }
})
```

95 is ASCII character of `_` this jquery will detect of you write `_` return false will stop writing it

Comment: can you edit the above with this code https://plnkr.co/edit/Solap6eBGssvn7wVjkFn?p=preview

Comment: Down-voted for answering a JavaScript question with jQuery. Requiring someone to dump another 70KB to achieve something simple is completely unprofessional.